# Can Pattern Matching be used for list membership?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I know that I can use guards to check if a value occurs in a list, but I am wondering whether *pattern matching alone* can be used for this too.

```hs
-- Using guards
f :: [Int] -> Int
f xs
    | 42 `elem` xs = 42
    | otherwise = 0

-- Using pattern matching?
g :: [Int] -> Int
g (_:)*42:_ = 42  -- i.e. zero or more elements: we discard until 42, followed by whatever.
g _         = 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. With literal `Int` values only; recursively.

```
-- Using pattern matching alone
g :: [Int] -> Int
g (42:_) = 42 
g []     = 0
g (_:r)  = g r
```

Testing:

```
> g [1..50]
42

> g [1]
0
```

There's no regex-like constructs in patterns though. I wish we could write something like

```
foo [...xs, 42, ...ys] = xs ++ ys
foo _ = []
```

but we can't.

Update: after the suggestion by [@chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485938/can-pattern-matching-be-used-for-list-membership/60487139?noredirect=1#comment107006358_60487139); using *view patterns*;

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

g2 (break (== 42) -> (_,[])) = 0   -- 0,  if not found
g2 _ = 42                          -- 42, otherwise
```

I'm not sure whether it counts as "patterns alone" though, as it uses a *"regular"* standard function, `break`. The advantage is, it's not just with literals anymore.

Comment: While the serious answer on lists is "no", as you wrote, in theory one could make `foo (Just (xs, ys) <- splitAtP 42) = ...` work with view patterns and a suitable definition of `splitAtP`. It's probably not worth it, though.

Comment: `splitAtP` then would be just a regular function though? (what you show is pattern guard, I think, not a view pattern, that'd be `foo (splitAt 42 -> Just (xs,ys))`, but both just use regular functions there). but yes, thanks, view pattern would do what I "wished" there, indeed. :) so, just `foo (break (==42) -> ...)` would probably work. or something like it. I don't know if it counts as "patterns alone"...

Comment: Yes, it would be a regular function. (Indeed, I got the syntax wrong)

Answer (score 3):

short answer: no
long answer:
patterns are defined recursively as following:

```
pattern := variable
         | constant
         | C p1 p2... where C is a constructor and p1 p2... are patterns
         | variable@pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, in a way, but it requires enabling a GHC extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns -#}

g :: [Int] -> Int
g ((42 `elem`) -> True) = 42
g _         = 0
```

A pattern of the form `f -> v` matches an argument `x` if `f x` matches `v`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can Pattern Matching be used for list membership?

Only by applying patterns recursively, e.g.

```hs
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem x [] = False
elem x (y:ys) = x == y || elem x ys
```

So none of the patterns `[]` and `y:ys` check for list membership themselves.

But in combination with recursion they're instrumental.

Answer (score 0):

"Zero or more elements we discard until 42, followed by whatever."

Nope.

This pattern will match only lists with `42` as second element. `:` is list constructor, thing that composes\decomposes list in unique way, not a concatenation, and concatenation is "to complex" to be used in pattern matching.